# React: How can i run a function from another Component with state Variables

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have this free components:

my LoginForm:

```js
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { Pane, TextInputField, Checkbox, Button } from "evergreen-ui";
import { validateEmail, validatePassword } from "./FormValidator";

class LoginForm extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      passwordErr: {
        status: false,
        value: ""
      },
      emailErr: {
        status: false,
        value: ""
      },
      email: "",
      password: "",
      CheckBoxchecked: false
    };
    this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
    this.handleCheckbox = this.handleCheckbox.bind(this);
  }

  handleEmailInput = e => {
    const email = e.target.value;
    this.setState({ email: email });
  };

  handlePasswordInput = e => {
    const password = e.target.value;
    this.setState({ password: password });
  };

  handleCheckbox() {
    this.setState({
      CheckBoxchecked: !this.state.CheckBoxchecked
    });
  }

  handleSubmit() {
    if (this.checkFormStatus()) {
      alert("Form OK");
    }
  }

  checkFormStatus() {
    // form validation middleware
    const { email, password } = this.state;
    const emailErr = validateEmail(email);
    const passwordErr = validatePassword(password);

    if (!emailErr.status && !passwordErr.status) {
      return true;
    } else {
      this.setState({
        emailErr,
        passwordErr
      });
      return false;
    }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <Pane padding={15}>
        <TextInputField
          tabIndex={0}
          required
          isInvalid={this.state.emailErr.status}
          validationMessage={
            this.state.emailErr.status ? this.state.emailErr.value : false
          }
          onChange={this.handleEmailInput}
          value={this.state.email}
          appearance="neutral"
          type="email"
          label="Your email-address"
          inputHeight={36}
          //description="We’ll need your email-address to create an new account"
        />
        <TextInputField
          required
          validationMessage={
            this.state.passwordErr.status ? this.state.passwordErr.value : false
          }
          isInvalid={this.state.passwordErr.status}
          onChange={this.handlePasswordInput}
          value={this.state.password}
          appearance="neutral"
          label="Your Password"
          type="password"
          inputHeight={36}
          //description="Create a secure password to protect your account"
        />
        <Checkbox
          label="Keep me logged in"
          checked={this.state.CheckBoxchecked}
          onChange={this.handleCheckbox}
        />
      </Pane>
    );
  }
}
export default LoginForm;
```

my export LoginFormButton:

```js
export class LoginFormButton extends Component {

  render() {
    return (
      <Button
        appearance="primary"
        marginLeft={8}
        marginRight={16}
        intent="success"
        onClick={} //How can i call handleSubmit() from here?
      >
        Login
      </Button>
    );
  }
}
```

and my Dialog...

```js
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import LoginForm from './LoginForm';
import LoginFormButton from './LoginFormButton';

class LoginDialog extends Components {

  render(
    return(
      <Dialog>
        <LoginForm/>
        <div className="Footer">
          <LoginFormButton/>
        </div>
      </Dialog>   
    );  
  )
}
```

I have the function `handleSubmit()` stored in the LoginForm Component. I want to call these function from the LoginFormButton. This Button is contained in the Dialog Component:

[image]

How can i do this? Thanks for your answer and our help. I am a beginner, so i don't exactly know, how can i implement this.

Comment: Where do you render a <LoginFormButton />? Is that in LoginForm but somehow omitted from the example code? Or is it in some other component?

Comment: @NicholasTower thanks for your answer. Please take a look to my edit question

Comment: What's stopping you from putting the function in a separate file and just importing that file in both components?

Comment: @OrthoHomeDefense thanks for your answer... please can you show, how can i do that, so the Form with Validation is still working? I am a beginner and i don't know exactly, how can i do that...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like, you want to have a LoginForm Component, and a LoginFormButton to handle form submit.

```js
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { Pane, TextInputField, Checkbox, Button } from "evergreen-ui";
import { validateEmail, validatePassword } from "./FormValidator";

const LoginFormButton = ({ handleSubmit }) => {
    return (
      <Button
        appearance="primary"
        marginLeft={8}
        marginRight={16}
        intent="success"
        onClick={() => handleSubmit()} // or just -> onClick={handleSubmit}
      >
        Login
      </Button>
    );
}

class LoginForm extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      passwordErr: {
        status: false,
        value: ""
      },
      emailErr: {
        status: false,
        value: ""
      },
      email: "",
      password: "",
      CheckBoxchecked: false
    };
    this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
    this.handleCheckbox = this.handleCheckbox.bind(this);
  }

  handleEmailInput = e => {
    const email = e.target.value;
    this.setState({ email: email });
  };

  handlePasswordInput = e => {
    const password = e.target.value;
    this.setState({ password: password });
  };

  handleCheckbox() {
    this.setState({
      CheckBoxchecked: !this.state.CheckBoxchecked
    });
  }

  handleSubmit() {
    if (this.checkFormStatus()) {
      alert("Form OK");
    }
  }

  checkFormStatus() {
    // form validation middleware
    const { email, password } = this.state;
    const emailErr = validateEmail(email);
    const passwordErr = validatePassword(password);

    if (!emailErr.status && !passwordErr.status) {
      return true;
    } else {
      this.setState({
        emailErr,
        passwordErr
      });
      return false;
    }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <Pane padding={15}>
        <TextInputField
          tabIndex={0}
          required
          isInvalid={this.state.emailErr.status}
          validationMessage={
            this.state.emailErr.status ? this.state.emailErr.value : false
          }
          onChange={this.handleEmailInput}
          value={this.state.email}
          appearance="neutral"
          type="email"
          label="Your email-address"
          inputHeight={36}
          //description="We’ll need your email-address to create an new account"
        />
        <TextInputField
          required
          validationMessage={
            this.state.passwordErr.status ? this.state.passwordErr.value : false
          }
          isInvalid={this.state.passwordErr.status}
          onChange={this.handlePasswordInput}
          value={this.state.password}
          appearance="neutral"
          label="Your Password"
          type="password"
          inputHeight={36}
          //description="Create a secure password to protect your account"
        />
        <Checkbox
          label="Keep me logged in"
          checked={this.state.CheckBoxchecked}
          onChange={this.handleCheckbox}
        />
        <LoginFormButton
          handleSubmit={this.handleSubmit}
        />
      </Pane>
    );
  }
}
export default LoginForm;
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
```

1) Validation will happen in LoginForm Component, unless you pass `this.state.password` and `this.state.email` to `LoginFormButton` Component. I wouldn't advice to do that, as validation can be handled in LoginForm Component.

2) HandleSubmit function can be passed to  `LoginFormButton` component as props from `LoginForm` component, and can be directly used within the component.

I would advice to follow JS standards for naming conventions(camelCases) in your state variable. And use Arrow Functions so that you don't have to bind function explicitly, unless otherwise.

I Changed you `LoginFormButton` to a stateless Component, as it does not require a state. It is better that way, and what React Community encourages.

Comment: thanks for your answer, but i don't want to use the LoginFormButton inside the LoginForm Component. I want to match both inside a Dialog Component. Please take a look to my edit question.

Comment: You mean like `class LoginDialog extends Components { render( return( <Dialog>  <LoginForm/><LoginFormButton/>  </Dialog>   );  )}` ?? .. In that case, move your LoginForm functions to Dialog Component. and pass them as props to both components. OR `class LoginDialog extends Components { render( return( <Dialog>  <LoginForm/> </Dialog>   );  )}` would work perfect, no need to make any other change.

Answer (score 0):

Check below corrected code

**LoginForm component**

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { Pane, TextInputField, Checkbox, Button } from "evergreen-ui";
import { validateEmail, validatePassword } from "./FormValidator";

class LoginForm extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      passwordErr: {
        status: false,
        value: ""
      },
      emailErr: {
        status: false,
        value: ""
      },
      email: "",
      password: "",
      CheckBoxchecked: false
    };
    this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
    this.handleCheckbox = this.handleCheckbox.bind(this);
  }

  handleEmailInput = e => {
    const email = e.target.value;
    this.setState({ email: email });
  };

  handlePasswordInput = e => {
    const password = e.target.value;
    this.setState({ password: password });
  };

  handleCheckbox() {
    this.setState({
      CheckBoxchecked: !this.state.CheckBoxchecked
    });
  }

  handleSubmit() {
    if (this.checkFormStatus()) {
      alert("Form OK");
    }
  }

  checkFormStatus() {
    // form validation middleware
    const { email, password } = this.state;
    const emailErr = validateEmail(email);
    const passwordErr = validatePassword(password);

    if (!emailErr.status && !passwordErr.status) {
      return true;
    } else {
      this.setState({
        emailErr,
        passwordErr
      });
      return false;
    }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <Pane padding={15}>
        <TextInputField
          tabIndex={0}
          required
          isInvalid={this.state.emailErr.status}
          validationMessage={
            this.state.emailErr.status ? this.state.emailErr.value : false
          }
          onChange={this.handleEmailInput}
          value={this.state.email}
          appearance="neutral"
          type="email"
          label="Your email-address"
          inputHeight={36}
          //description="We’ll need your email-address to create an new account"
        />
        <TextInputField
          required
          validationMessage={
            this.state.passwordErr.status ? this.state.passwordErr.value : false
          }
          isInvalid={this.state.passwordErr.status}
          onChange={this.handlePasswordInput}
          value={this.state.password}
          appearance="neutral"
          label="Your Password"
          type="password"
          inputHeight={36}
          //description="Create a secure password to protect your account"
        />
        <Checkbox
          label="Keep me logged in"
          checked={this.state.CheckBoxchecked}
          onChange={this.handleCheckbox}
        />
        <div className="Footer">
          <LoginFormButton handleSubmit={this.handleSubmit} />
        </div>
      </Pane>
    );
  }
}
export default LoginForm;
```

**LoginFormButton component**

```
export class LoginFormButton extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {

    };
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Button
          appearance="primary"
          marginLeft={8}
          marginRight={16}
          intent="success"
          onClick={this.props.handleSubmit}
        >
          Login
        </Button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

**Dialog component**

```
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import LoginForm from './LoginForm';
import LoginFormButton from './LoginFormButton';

class LoginDialog extends Components {

  render(
    return(
      <Dialog>
        <LoginForm/>
      </Dialog>   
    );  
  )
}
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, i want to match the LoginForm and the LoginFormButton to a Dialog... How can i do that? please take a look to my updated question... i am a beginner and i don't know exactly, how can i do that...

Comment: Sorry your question isn't clear. Can you explain it well

Comment: Sorry that I have expressed myself unclear, I have updated my question, hope you unterstand me now

Answer (score 0):

I recommend that you do not put the business logic in the button component. The button's only job should be to notify whoever's using it that the button has been clicked. This is done by passing a prop to the button:

```
export class LoginFormButton extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Button
        appearance="primary"
        marginLeft={8}
        marginRight={16}
        intent="success"
        onClick={this.props.onClick}
      >
        Login
      </Button>
    );
  }
}
```

Then whatever component uses the prop will be where the business logic happens. The other solutions assumed the login form button would be part of the login form, and that's probably how i would do it as well. So my recommendation is to take this part out of LoginDialog:

```
<div className="Footer">
  <LoginFormButton/>
</div>
```

Move it into LoginForm.js, and add the callback:

```
render() {
  return (
    <Pane padding={15}>
      {/* inputs and checkbox components omitted */}
      <div className="Footer" onClick={this.handleSubmit}>
        <LoginFormButton/>
      </div>
    </Pane>
  )
}
```

If you can't do move the button into the form for some reason, then you'll have more work to do. You'll want to move the business logic up to the component which is the shared ancestor of both the button and the text inputs -- ie, LoginDialog. So you'd take most of the code that's currently in LoginForm and move it to LoginDialog instead. This includes moving the state up from LoginForm to LoginDialog. LoginForm will then need callbacks to pass relevant changes back to the loginDialog, so that the dialog can update its state. An when the button is pressed, that event will go to handleSubmit in LoginDialog.

This act of moving state up to a parent is fairly common in react development, enough so that it's mentioned in react's tutorial page here: https://reactjs.org/tutorial/tutorial.html#lifting-state-up . So it's a valid way to solve the problem, but in this case i think you're probably better off just moving the button into the form

Comment: many thanks for your answer. That would be very helpfully for me